# Ramsey number for small poset $R(\diamondsuit)=4$, $R(\diamondsuit,\diamondsuit)=...$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I have exercise to prove $R(\diamondsuit)=4$, I try to solve this exercise by this proof :

> $\ge$ In $Q_3$ (Here $Q_3$ denotes a Boolean lattice of dimension $3$) we can colour the upper two layers red and the lower two layers blue to avoid a monochromatic $2-diamond poset \mathcal D_k$ ($\diamondsuit$) .
>
> $\le$ Consider any colouring of $Q_4$. Asume without loss of generality that $\emptyset$ is red. We consider into two cases :
>
> **Case 1: 1234 is red**. If there are two incomparable red elements, then together with $\emptyset$ and $1234$, they form a red $\diamondsuit$. If, on the other hand, the red elements are subset of a chain, without loss of generality {$\emptyset,1,12,123,1234$}, then everything else is blue and {$2,23,24,234$} forms a blue $\diamondsuit$.
>
> **Case 2: 1234 is blue**. $Q_4$ contains a monochromatic $\mathcal N$ (poset $A\lt C, B\lt C, B\lt D$). Note that this $\mathcal N$ will not make use of $\emptyset$ or $123$, since $\mathcal N$ has neither maximum nor minimum. If the copy of $\mathcal N$ is blue, we restrict it to a blue $\mathcal V$  and add $1234$ to obtain a blue $\diamondsuit$. If it is red, we restrict it to a red and add $\emptyset$ to obtain a red $\diamondsuit$.

How about $R(\diamondsuit,\diamondsuit)= . . .$

Anyone can help to solve $R(\diamondsuit,\diamondsuit)= . . .$ or reference to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more? Does the poset have to contain two disjoint diamonds of the same color, or what?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what $R(\diamond,\diamond)$ means in this context, but here are two papers which consider this type of problem:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11083-016-9399-7
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11083-017-9449-9

Comment: These resources might not be available in the future, so it is better to have a self-contained answer. Can you elaborate on the content of these papers?

Comment: The first paper is Boolean Lattices: Ramsey Properties and Embeddings by Axenovich and Walzer, and the second is Ramsey Numbers for Partially-Ordered Sets by myself and Stolee. Both papers consider the question: Given posets $P_1,\dots,P_t$ what is the smallest $N$ for which any $t$-coloring of the Boolean lattice of order $N$ contains a copy of some $P_i$ in color $i$? The main difference between the papers is that the former requires the posets to be induced whereas the latter does not.